# Match only exact numbers, not pre of suffixed with slash/dash etc

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches only numbers of length 7 (they can have leading zeros). I used the following super easy regex: `\b[0-9]{7}\b`. However, this regex also matches numbers in e.g. `5254-6408499` and `(0241)4013999` (see https://regex101.com/r/zF5hV7/1).

How can I prevent them from being matched? I only want numbers of length 7 having leading and/or trailing spaces.

Comment: You probably want to use negative lookarounds for this.

Comment: Thanks, tried `\b(?<!(-|\(|\/|\)))[0-9]{7}(?!-|\(|\/|\))\b` and seems to work. But seeing the comments below I made it a bit too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the regular expression flavor, you could create your own boundaries:

```
(?<=^| )\d{7}(?= |$)
```

This asserts that either the beginning of the string or a space precedes moving on to matching exactly 7 digits only if the engine asserts that either a space or the end of string follows.

Comment: I chose this answer so I didn't have to work with a capture group.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Perl `Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<=^| )\d{7}(?= |$)/` :(

Comment: You could substitute it, `(?:^| )\K`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:^|\s)([0-9]{7})(?:\s|$)
```

and grab captured group #1

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zF5hV7/2)